# How to oversample a dataframe in Pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, oversampling

How to oversample a dataframe in pyspark?

```
df.sample(fractions, seed)
```

Which only sample a fraction of the df, it can't oversample.

Comment: By oversample, do you mean increase the number of samples as compared to original? if yes, how do you plan to do that, by duplicating records or by applying some oversampling algorithm?

Comment: Define what you mean by "oversample". Try to provide an [mcve] if it's appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You could over-sample by making use of the [sample method](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sample) as follows:

```
df.sample(withReplacement=True, total_percent_of_upsample, seed)

sample(withReplacement, fraction, seed=None)
```

The `True` indicates that you want to sample with replacement.